# mysql ibd file in file system

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

I am in searching of where mysql stored its indexes for innodb engine.I found it stores in ibd file but where I will found those files on system.Can anyone help please?

Comment: Jeremy Cole has a python tool for inspecting InnoDB tablespaces.

Answer (score 1):

In InnoDB both data and indexes are stored together, there is no separate file for indexes. Within your MySQL install directory you will find directories for each database, and within each database directory will be the tablespace files. Depending on whether you have InnoDB File-Per-Table enabled or not, you will see individual files per table or not.

Comment: Okay.Then how can I see the records for a specific index.

Comment: What do you mean show records for a specific index? If you know what the index is you can just query for those values, if you don't know the index you can view the indexes on a table with `show index from table_name;`